# How to combine hex values in real-time?

Tags: c, file-handling

To give a context, I have an incoming stream of Hex values that is getting written to a CSV file which are in the format shown below.

```
20 5a 20 5e 20 7b 20 b1 20 64 20 f8 ...
```

I can not change the way the data is flowing in, but before it gets written to a CSV file I want it in this format below.

```
205a 205e 207b 20b1 2064 20f8 ...
```

As the data is coming, I need to process it and store it in the format shown above. One of the ways I tried was just bitshifting and doing logical OR which would store the result in a variable. But all I have here is a pointer pointing to a buffer where the data will be flowing into. I have something like this.

```
uint8_t *curr_ptr;
uint8_t* dec_buffer=(uint8_t*)calloc(4000,sizeof(uint8_t)*max_len);
init=dec_buffer;
curr_ptr=init+((count)*max_len);

for(int j=17;j<=145;j+=1){

        fprintf(f_write[file_count],"%02x ", *(curr_ptr+j));

if(j>0 && j%145==0){

       fprintf(f_write[file_count],"\n");
```

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are two very different languages. What you want to do could (and likely would) be implemented very differently in the different languages. So please tell us the language you're actually using yourself.

Comment: If real time is so important, just stream as binary output first (or dump your binary buffer to file when you are done collecting). Then write an offline application that can convert to the csv format you want. Oh and your code looks like it is "C" not "C++".

Comment: Probably easier just to treat it as a string and remove every other space

Comment: Indeed, can you do this as simple text processing? Simplest may be: read char by char. Ignore input spaces. Count output characters, and add apace to output after every four characters.

Comment: There is never a reason to use something like `*(curr_ptr+j)` when writing C. Instead write `curr_ptr[j]`.

Comment: Also where is the actual data coming in? All this does it to allocate a zeroed-out buffer then write all zeroes to a file. Is this pseudo code or what?

Comment: The OP needs to clarify if the input stream is a series of unsigned binary bytes or a series of ASCII characters (2 hex digits followed by a space). Suggesting a CSV will "appear" like the concatenation of 2 binary bytes is ludicrous. A CSV **is** a text file. What does the incoming data actually look like? (And, invoking `fprintf()` for every byte or byte pair is definitely going to slow things down.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Couldn't reply sooner, apologies! 
@PepijnKramer Yes that makes sense but in my case its unnecessary. 
@Lundin This is not the complete code. I have excluded the part that includes socket initialization and stuff.
@Fe2O3 Yes, input stream is a series of ASCII characters. I would later want to convert them to Decimal also. What else would you suggest to use instead of `fprintf()` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you want to remove every other space. Why not something like this?

```
for(int j=17;j<=145;j+=1){
    fprintf(f_write[file_count], j%2 ? "%02x " : "%02x", *(curr_ptr+j));
```

Not sure if you should be printing spaces after the odd values of `j` or the even ones, but you can sort that out.

Comment: This will print extra space at the end. Of course we don't know if this matters.

Comment: @hyde Yes, but the original code does that too. I was more worried about what to do if the overall number of bytes is odd (which it seems to be given the loop limits), but that's also unspecified by the OP.

Comment: I think the format should be "%02x"

Comment: @ulix Yes, I didn't spot that, I just copied the OP code. I'll edit.

Comment: @john Yes the correct format is `%02x`. I forgot to change it back while posting. 
@hyde Extra space is fine in the end, it doesn't matter.